# ipywidgets 'button.on_click' command not returning any output

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I have been creating a simple program which uses checkboxes and radio buttons to ask the user for their preferences of genre and age for movies, then filters a dataframe I created based on these criteria to return a movie recommendation.

I have tested the underlying function and know that it works. However, when I press my button linked to the function by the button.on_click(function) command, nothing is returned. When I click the button, nothing happens.

I copied the function to another cell where I used defined variables to mimic a user selecting 'Action', 'Comedy' and '80s and 90s are fine'. For whatever reason, once I run this cell based on those parameters and THEN try to run the original program with the corresponding selections, it will actually return the result. But ONLY that result, even if I select new genres in my checkboxes.

Here is what I have now.

```py
mylbl1 = wd.Label( 'What are you in the mood for? Select 2 genres:' )
display(mylbl1)

action = wd.Checkbox( description = 'Action' )
display(action)

adventure = wd.Checkbox( description = 'Adventure' )
display(adventure)

comedy = wd.Checkbox( description = 'Comedy' )
display(comedy)

crime = wd.Checkbox( description = 'Crime' )
display(crime)

drama = wd.Checkbox( description = 'Drama' )
display(drama)

fantasy = wd.Checkbox( description = 'Fantasy' )
display(fantasy)

horror = wd.Checkbox( description = 'Horror' )
display(horror)

romance = wd.Checkbox( description = 'Romance' )
display(romance)

scifi = wd.Checkbox( description = 'Sci-Fi' )
display(scifi)

mystery = wd.Checkbox( description = 'Mystery' )
display(mystery)

thriller = wd.Checkbox( description = 'Thriller' )
display(thriller)

history = wd.Checkbox( description = 'Historical' )
display(history)

mylbl2 = wd.Label( 'Do you like older movies?' )
display(mylbl2)

age = wd.RadioButtons(options = [ 'I prefer newer movies', '80s and 90s are fine', '60s and 70s are fine', '40s and 50s are fine', 'Black and white is fine', 'Silent is fine' ] )
display(age)

myBtn = wd.Button( description = 'Gimme!' )
display(myBtn)

movies = pd.read_csv('movies.csv')

def mymovie(a):
    genres = 0
    mygenres = []
    while genres<2:
        if action == True:
            mygenres.append('Action')
            genres+=1
        if adventure == True:
            mygenres.append('Adventure')
            genres+=1
        if comedy == True:
            mygenres.append('Comedy')
            genres+=1
        if crime == True:
            mygenres.append('Crime')
            genres+=1
        if drama == True:
            mygenres.append('Drama')
            genres+=1
        if fantasy == True:
            mygenres.append('Fantasy')
            genres+=1
        if horror == True:
            mygenres.append('Horror')
            genres+=1
        if romance == True:
            mygenres.append('Romance')
            genres+=1
        if scifi == True:
            mygenres.append('Sci-Fi')
            genres+=1
        if mystery == True:
            mygenres.append('Mystery')
            genres+=1
        if thriller == True:
            mygenres.append('Thriller')
            genres+=1
        if history == True:
            mygenres.append('History')
            genres+=1
    mygenre1 = mygenres[0]
    mygenre2 = mygenres[1]
    if age == 'I prefer newer movies':
        movie_age = 2000
    elif age == '80s and 90s are fine':
        movie_age = 1980
    elif age == '60s and 70s are fine':
        movie_age = 1960
    elif age == '40s and 50s are fine':
        movie_age = 1940
    elif age == 'Black and white is fine':
        movie_age = 1930
    elif age == 'Silent is fine':
        movie_age = 1900
    mymovies = movies[((movies.genre1 == mygenre1) | (movies.genre2 == mygenre1) | (movies.genre3 == mygenre1)) & ((movies.genre1 == mygenre2) | (movies.genre2 == mygenre2) | (movies.genre3 == mygenre2)) & (movies.year>=movie_age)]
    mymovies = mymovies.sort_values('rating', ascending = False)
    themovie = mymovies.head(1)
    thetitle = themovie.iloc[0][1]
    thedirector = themovie.iloc[0][2]
    theyear = themovie.iloc[0][3]
    display(str(thedirector) + '\'s ' + str(thetitle) + ' (' + str(theyear) + ')')

myBtn.on_click(mymovie)
```

After extensive research on GitHub and stackoverflow I have tried more solutions than I can reasonably recount in detail. I've tried to reproduce every solution I could find, and I can't find any threads about this I haven't already tried.

I tried using print rather than display for the final output of the function, and tried to embed that in output widgets and VBox widgets.

I tried defining an empty label which was updated with my desired output at the end of the function.

In all cases the issue persisted.

Would appreciate any help because I have been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please format the question to make it a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? For example, the question doesn't share information about `movies.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

1. The loop isn't necessary. Currently, your program is listening for the button click and then loops until two checkbox values are true. Ideally you should check for two checkboxes to have true values at the very beginning of the `mymovie` function, and then exit the function if they don't have two checkboxes selected
2. You should be checking the `value` property of each checkbox widget. IE `if action.value == True:`. Currently you're comparing a checkbox widget object against a boolean value which probably wasn't your intention.
3. You're using Python's bitwise operators (`|` and `&`) rather than logical operators (`and` and `or`). In particular, this line: `mymovies = movies[((movies.genre1 == mygenre1) | (movies.genre2 == mygenre1) | (movies.genre3 == mygenre1)) & ((movies.genre1 == mygenre2) | (movies.genre2 == mygenre2) | (movies.genre3 == mygenre2)) & (movies.year>=movie_age)]` is doing a whole bunch of bitwise operations, however I believe you meant to do logical operations.

This is what I noticed on my first sweep of the program. I think you'll run into scoping issues with the `movie_age` variable as well. You've declared a variable `movie_age` several times within `if` blocks. Later in the program you try and reference it again, however this time it's outside the scope where you defined it. Move the declaration/initialization of `movie_age` outside the scope of the `if` blocks such that it can be referenced later.

Like the other poster mentioned, can you provide a sample of the movies.csv file? It would help others to troubleshoot.